# How to Change Selected Item and Border Color of ListPicker

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've noticed that the currently selected item and the border of the ListPicker use the device's accent color. How might I change this to a custom color? Regardless of whether the user's theme is dark or light, when a user selects the ListPicker to choose an item, and when an item is selected, I'd like to have that item's foreground and the ListPicker's border brush to be the same color (for instance Cyan #FF1BA1E2).

Comment: Have you tried editing the default template of the control ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly what to change. I just need the BorderBrush and currently selected item's Foreground to be Cyan for example in the same instances as when the default ListPicker shows the PhoneAccentBrush.